# LinkedHashMap as a parent of a spring bean

Tags: java, spring

there is a next construction in spring context:

```
<util:map id="testMap" map-class="java.util.LinkedHashMap">
      <entry key="testKey">
      ...doesn't matter
</util:map>

<bean id="childTestMap" parent="testMap"></bean>
```

Is that true ? I mean is that working configuration ? 
I'm asking because I see next stack trace when I'm trying to run that:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'testMap' is defined

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should work. Did you check on the log that testMap was created successfully?

Comment: Thank you guys, I've tested it and actually we can cast util:map to spring child bean.